# Is there any workaround to install a gmail add-on developed by other in a gmail.com account?

Tags: gmail-addons

At this moment, you can install your own add-ons and add-ons from other developer if your account and its account are of the same domain, but if the domain is not from an institution and they are standard gmail accounts.

In the other hand anyone with a gmail account can copy scripts and manifest from one add-on and create one to use, but it is not a good experience.

I know that Google plans to open the add-ons market but is there a workaround to do this now?

Thank you very much

Comment: 1 workaround is sharing the apps-script project itself with the person and then that person can deploy it for herself. I don't know how you would prevent them from seeing the code though.. Please comment if you have already found a better way..

Comment: The matter on this is not let users see the code, is that is a really bad user experience. At this moment I think that it is the only way, so I did this:

https://javilopezg.com/gmail-add-ons-how-to-be-on-all-desktops-and-mobiles-with-a-simple-app/

I was thinking about automatizing this "installation" process in some way, maybe with an Elza script or something similar. However I did not finally do this because it has no sense get a lot of installations, it is like come back to the year 2000 xD